# Adding C++ sources with 'Link to file' option

Tags: android, c++, makefile

I try to add some C/C++ sources into JNI folder by dragging from explorer and choosing 'Link to files' option from the File Operation dialog.

How to add those sources into Android.mk makefile ?

I tried combination

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += source.cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += c:/full/path/to/file/source.cpp
```

but nothing works. Each time error appears 'make: *** No rule to make target.........'

So any suggestions ?

Thanks

P.S. If I choose 'Copy files' option -- everything is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working android.mk file for building a static library from 2 cpp files:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE :=arm

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
          mysource1.cpp \
          mysource2.cpp \

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -lz -lm -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```